# How to change my application icon in Android Google Assistant shortcut menu?

Tags: android, google-assistant, android-shortcut

I'm making an app that works with Google Assistant's voice recognizer, and everything works fine except for the icon.

However, I'm not sure if the app icon will be changed to my app icon when I publish it on the Google Play Store.

How to change icon below?(name Vendict for NFC)

[image]